# Program hangs up if console input is a large matrix, but works flawlesly when inputting from a file

Tags: c++

I need to find the longest distance in a matrix of size N x M where after each move(only right or down) the difference of the next tile - the current tile is <= than k, and write the distance size, starting tile, and the list of moves from start to end(j-right, l-down). I've used Breadth First Search for this, and the program works, however when using the input of a matrix of size 200 x 200 the program hangs up if I enter the data from the console, and does nothing. However when reading from a file, this problem doesn't occur, and works flawlesly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct pr {
    int i;
    int j;
};

void read(int arr[][301], int &n, int &m, int &k) {
    ifstream be("be.txt");
    int i, j;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

bool checkRight(int arr[][301], int i, int j, int k, int m) {
    if (j + 1 <= m && abs(arr[i][j + 1] - arr[i][j]) <= k)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

bool checkDownwards(int arr[][301], int i, int j, int k, int n) {
    if (i + 1 <= n && abs(arr[i + 1][j] - arr[i][j]) <= k)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}


void bfs(int dist[][301], int arr[][301], bool visited[][301], int i, int j, int n, int m, int k, int &max, pr &po, vector<int> &resol) {
    int maxDist;
    int l, p;
    pr prev[301][301];
    for (l = 1; l <= n; l++) {
        for (p = 1; p <= m; p++) {
            prev[l][p].i = 0;
            prev[l][p].j = 0;
        }
    }
    pr pos;
    pos.i = 0;
    pos.j = 0;
    vector<int> res;
    queue<pr> q;
    pr next;
    next.i = i;
    next.j = j;
    for (l = 1; l <= n; l++) {
        for (p = 1; p <= m; p++) {
            dist[l][p] = 0;
        }
    }
    dist[i][j] = 0;
    visited[i][j] = 1;
    q.push(next);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        pr front = q.front();
        visited[front.i][front.j] = 1;
        q.pop();
        if (checkRight(arr, front.i, front.j, k, m) == 1) {
            next.i = front.i;
            next.j = front.j + 1;
            q.push(next);
            dist[front.i][front.j + 1] = dist[front.i][front.j] + 1;
            maxDist = dist[front.i][front.j + 1];
            pos.i = next.i;
            pos.j = next.j;
            prev[next.i][next.j].i = front.i;
            prev[next.i][next.j].j = front.j;
        }
        if (checkDownwards(arr, front.i, front.j, k, n) == 1) {
            next.i = front.i + 1;
            next.j = front.j;
            q.push(next);
            dist[front.i + 1][front.j] = dist[front.i][front.j] + 1;
            maxDist = dist[front.i + 1][front.j];
            pos.i = next.i;
            pos.j = next.j;
            prev[next.i][next.j].i = front.i;
            prev[next.i][next.j].j = front.j;
        }
    }

    if (maxDist > max) {
        max = maxDist;
        po.i = i;
        po.j = j;
        resol.clear();
        next.i = pos.i;
        next.j = pos.j;
        while (next.i != i or next.j != j) {
            if (next.i == prev[next.i][next.j].i) {
                resol.push_back(1);
                next.j = prev[next.i][next.j].j;
            }
            if (next.j == prev[next.i][next.j].j) {
                resol.push_back(0);
                next.i = prev[next.i][next.j].i;
            }
        }
    }

}

void search(int arr[][301], int n, int m, int k) {
    int max = 0;
    int dist[301][301];
    bool visited[301][301] = {0};
    int i, j;
    vector<int> resol;
    pr po;
    po.i = 0;
    po.j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            if (visited[i][j] == 0)
                bfs(dist, arr, visited, i, j, n, m, k, max, po, resol);
        }
    }
    cout << max << endl;
    cout << po.i << " " << po.j << endl;
    for (i = resol.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (resol[i] == 0)
            cout << "L";
        else
            cout << "J";
    }
}

int main() {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int n, m, k;
    int arr[301][301];
    read(arr, n, m, k);
    search(arr, n, m, k);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(stop - start);
    cout<<endl<<duration.count();
}
```

```
Input 1:
5 4 1
7 7 9 7
4 5 3 4
6 6 5 2
4 7 8 2
1 2 3 4
```

```
Output 1:
4
2 1
JLLJ
0
```

```
Input 2:
https://pastebin.com/FQY3xVCv
```

```
Output 2:
If I use console input:
Hangs up
If I use file input:
20
183 53
LLJJJJJLJLLJLLLLLJLL
3
```

Comment: Compilers usually store local variables on the stack. The stack is a limited resource. For example on Windows the default stack size for a process is only a single megabyte. You go way outside of that with all your arrays. That will lead to the problem that this site is named after: A stack overflow.

Comment: I think you're better of using a std::vector<std::vector<int>> for this code. It will allocate memory on the heap instead of the stack. It also allows you to not allocate more memory then you need. The actual array size is determinded at runtime anyway since it depends on our input

Comment: Are you seriously entering 40,000 integers in the console? Please say that you're redirecting the file rather than typing them by hand.

Comment: Haha, of course not. I pasted them with ctrl-v.